# Asymptote fill area between two contours

Tags: asymptote

I use `Asymptote` to make the graphics. I have two curves defined as contours C_1 and C_2. I want to fill the area
between the two curves. The problem is that contour returns a `guide`
structure in Asymptote, and this is not accepted to to `buildcycle` command. Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem ? Thanks.
This is the code I use and which produces the two curves, but fails to fill area between these.

```
import graph;
import patterns;
import contour; 

usepackage("mathrsfs");

size(8cm);

real eps=0.001;
real xmax=5.5,ymax=5.5;
pair af,ag;

real f(real x, real y) {return sqrt(1+x)-sqrt(x)+sqrt(1+y)-sqrt(y);}
real g(real x, real y) {return 1/sqrt(1+x)+1/sqrt(1+y);}

guide[][] Cf=contour(f,(eps,eps),(xmax,ymax),new real[] {1});
guide[][] Cg=contour(g,(eps,eps),(xmax,ymax),new real[] {1});

//these two lines are used to find intersection points
path D1=(0,ymax)--(xmax+eps,ymax);
path D2=(xmax,0)--(xmax,ymax+eps); 

draw(Cf);
draw(Cg);

//path pp=buildcycle(Cf,D1,Cg,D2);
// the preceding line produces and error if commented

xaxis(Label(scale(0.75)*"$x$"),xmax=6,Arrow);
yaxis(Label(rotate(90)*scale(0.75)*"$y$"),ymax=6,Arrow);

label("$\mathscr{C}_{1}$",(xmax,0.2));
label("$\mathscr{C}_{2}$",(xmax,1.9));
label("I"  ,(.2,.2));
label("II" ,(1.,1.));
label("III",(3.5,3.5));

end;
```

Comment: Is there some reason why you are using `contour` to produce the lines?  It seems a rather complicated way to produce a single curve.

Comment: Using f to write y = function (x) lead to a long expression. Around zero it requires large precision for fine tuned draw. Contour allows easier control over the drawing box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works when replacing `Cf` and `Cg` by `Cf[0][0]` and `Cg[0][0]`, which allows to obtain the desired (single) guides.

```
path pp=buildcycle(Cf[0][0],D1,Cg[0][0],D2);
```

Note that I've also slightly modified `D1` and `D2`: in your definitions, `D1`, `D2` and `pp` did *not* intersect anyway.

```
path D1=(0,ymax-eps)--(xmax+eps,ymax-eps);
path D2=(xmax-eps,0)--(xmax-eps,ymax+eps);
```

For proper explanations about how to use `contour`, see the very well-made (alas not complete) [tutorial on Asymptote](http://math.uchicago.edu/~cstaats/Charles_Staats_III/Notes_and_papers_files/asymptote_tutorial.pdf) by Charles Staats, p. 32.

```
import graph;
import patterns;
import contour; 

usepackage("mathrsfs");

size(8cm);

real eps=0.001;
real xmax=5.5,ymax=5.5;
pair af,ag;

real f(real x, real y) {return sqrt(1+x)-sqrt(x)+sqrt(1+y)-sqrt(y);}
real g(real x, real y) {return 1/sqrt(1+x)+1/sqrt(1+y);}

guide[][] Cf=contour(f,(eps,eps),(xmax,ymax),new real[] {1});
guide[][] Cg=contour(g,(eps,eps),(xmax,ymax),new real[] {1});

//these two lines are used to find intersection points
path D1=(0,ymax-eps)--(xmax+eps,ymax-eps);
path D2=(xmax-eps,0)--(xmax-eps,ymax+eps);

path pp=buildcycle(Cf[0][0],D1,Cg[0][0],D2); 
fill(pp,.8white); draw(pp);

xaxis(Label(scale(0.75)*"$x$"),xmax=6,Arrow);
yaxis(Label(rotate(90)*scale(0.75)*"$y$"),ymax=6,Arrow);

label("$\mathscr{C}_{1}$",(xmax,0.2));
label("$\mathscr{C}_{2}$",(xmax,1.9));
label("I"  ,(.2,.2));
label("II" ,(1.,1.));
label("III",(3.5,3.5));
```

[image]

Comment: Great, it works fine ! thank a lot fpast, for the answer and for the suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Just for comparison, here is a Metapost version.  There's no support for implicit equations or anything so clever (or complex) as Asymptote's `contour` facility, so I could not avoid some algebra to get the "long expression" that the OP was happy to avoid.  And to avoid overflows when `x` is near zero, I'm exploiting the facts that these two curves have a symmetry about the line through `(0,0)--(1,1)` and that C1 goes through `(9/16,9/16)` while C2 goes through `(3,3)` -- I therefore only use a loop to construct the curves to the right of these points; I then use MP's `reflectedabout` macro to create the required upper halves.

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);
u := 1cm;
path xx, yy, ff, gg;
xx = (1/2 left -- 6 right) scaled u;
yy = xx rotated 90;
drawarrow xx; drawarrow yy;

vardef f(expr x) = 
  save s; numeric s;
  s = (1+sqrt(x)-sqrt(1+x))**2;
  (1-2s+s**2)/(4s)
  enddef;

vardef g(expr x) = 
   (1+x)/(2+x-2*sqrt(1+x))-1
   enddef;

s = 0.05;
ff = ((9/16,9/16) for x = 9/16+s step s until 5.5: -- (x,f(x)) endfor) scaled u;
gg = ((3,3)       for x =    3+s step s until 5.5: -- (x,g(x)) endfor) scaled u;

ff := reverse ff reflectedabout(origin,(1,1)) & ff;
gg := reverse gg reflectedabout(origin,(1,1)) & gg;

path A;
A = ff -- reverse gg -- cycle;
fill A withcolor .9[blue,white];
draw ff;
draw gg;

string s; s = "";
for $=0,9/16u,3u:
  s := s & "I";
  label.urt(s,($,$));
  endfor

label.urt(btex ${\cal C}_1$ etex, point infinity of ff);
label.urt(btex ${\cal C}_2$ etex, point infinity of gg);

label.bot(btex $x$ etex, point 1 of xx);
label.lft(btex $y$ etex, point 1 of yy);

endfig;
end.
```

If you wanted to draw the ends of the area as well you could just replace my `draw ff; draw gg;` with `draw A`.

[image]